# awk-insert row with specific text within specific position

Tags: text, awk

I have a file where the first couple of rows start with `#` mark, then follow the classical netlist, where also can be there rows begin with `#` mark. I need to insert one row with text `protect` between block of first rows begining on `#` and first row of classical netlist. In the end of file i need insert row with word `unprotect`. It will be good to save this modified text to new file with specific name because of the original file protected.

Sample file:

```
// Generated for: spectre
// Design library name: Kovi
// Design cell name: T_Line
// Design view name: schematic
simulator lang=spectre
global 0
parameters frequency=3.8G Zo=250
// Library name: Kovi
// Cell name: T_Line
// View name: schematic
T8 (7 0 6 0) tline z0=Zo f=3.8G nl=0.5 vel=1
T7 (net034 0 net062 0) tline z0=Zo f=3.8G nl=0.5 vel=1
T5 (net021 0 4 0) tline z0=Zo f=3.8G nl=0.5 vel=1
T4 (net019 0 2 0) tline z0=Zo f=3.8G nl=0.5 vel=1
```

Comment: Do you specifically need this in `awk` code or will any shell-based solution be sufficient? Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: Can you post your email? I sent you sample file. thank you

Comment: @kovibb no, post the sample file on your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about `sed`

```
sed -e '/^#/,/^#/!iprotect'$'\n''$aunprotect'$'\n' input_file > new_file
```

Inserts 'protect' on a line by itself after the first block of commented lines, then adds 'unprotect' at the end.

Note: Because I use `$'\n'` in place of literal newline `bash` is assumed as the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)'d the post

```
awk 'BEGIN{ protected=""} { if($0 !~ /#/ && !protected){  protected="1"; print "protect";}  print $0}END{print "unprotect";}' input_file > output_file
```

As soon a row is detected without `#` as the first non-whitespace character, it will output a line with `protect`. At the end it will output a line for `unprotect`.

*Test file*

```
#
 #
#
     #Preceded by a tab
 begin protect

#

 before unprotect
```

*Result*

```
#
 #
#
     #Preceded by tab
protect
 begin protect

#

 before unprotect
unprotect
```

**Edit**: 
Removed the `[:space:]*` as it seems that is already handled by default.

---

**Support `//`**

If you wanted to support both `#` and `//` in the same script, the regex portion would change to `/#|\//`. *The special character `/` has to be escaped by using `\`.*

This would check for at least one `/`.

Adding a quantifier `{2}` will match `//` exactly: `/#|\/{2}/`

Comment: Excellent, this works. Very thanks. And how I must change the code if the "#" was echange to "//", please? I ask because "/" is special character.

Comment: Checking for the first `/` should be sufficient. Added that information to the post.

Comment: Thanks this is very usufull. However now i look that there are also files without //. In this case script insert  only 'unprotect' keyword. So exist some manner which firstly check if the file beginning with //?

Comment: Edit your original post with an example of the type of file you have described. I'm assuming at some point there is a line that doesn't contain `//` which would cause `protect` to be printed. Also, include the `awk` script are now using.